# Style a table column but miss the first row

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML table and I want to style one of the columns which I do with the following CSS.

```
    .tableStyles tr td:first-child + td + td {

    background-color:aquamarine

}
```

I would like to omit the first row from this so no styling is applied.  I tried something like this but it doesnt work.

```
    .tableStyles tr:not(first-child) td:first-child + td + td {

    background-color:aquamarine

}
```

Can you help?

Comment: `first-child` is a pseudo-class; and so prefixed by a colon. It should be `:first-child`. Correcting that typo, this should work.

Comment: Just to show that the problem is caused by the missing colon: [Here is an example using the same CSS as the question but with `not(:first-child)`](https://jsbin.com/jagude/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For skipping the 1st element of a given type and styling the 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements etc, using

```
:nth-of-type(n+2)
```

is an efficient solution.

Consequently, try:

```
.tableStyles tr:nth-of-type(n+2) td:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color:aquamarine
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*:nth-child(n+2)* will select starting from the 2nd

.tableStyles tr:nth-child(n+2)
{
    background-color:aquamarine
}